# Need to run a test step(groovy step) from another testsuite's setup script. But no testRunner available

Tags: groovy, soapui

i have a reusbale_libraries testSuite which has different reusable classes as test case/test script. One of the class is excelreader in a script. I need to call this excelreader script from another testsuite's setupscript and intitialize an array with all the data read from an excel sheet using the class in the excelreader script. The data in the array will be used by all the test cases in that testsuite.But Im not able to call the script from the testsuite as testsuite doesnt have testRunner variable. How to call that excelreader script?
If there's no way, what is the best way of maintaining the reusable libraries and using it in the testsuites/testcases/scripts?

```
Example code:
In TestSuite1's setup script: 

//def testRef=testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite 
4"].testCases["TestCase 1"]
//testRef.Run(testRunner,context) //throws exception testRunner not avl.

def tc=testSuite.project.testSuites["TestSuite 4"].testCases["TestCase 1"]
tc.testSteps["tc1_script2"].run(testSuite.testRunner,context) //this also 
throws exception

mobj=context.getProperty("obj")
log.info(mobj.fun())

In Testsuite2's Testcase1's testscript1:

class test1{
def fun(){return "test1"}
}
obj= new test1()
context.setProperty("obj",obj)
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy Hunter. i'm not able to see your comments. Dont know what happened. can you please let me know how to use runner or getTestRunner() in the testSuite's setup script and run the script in someother testsuite's testcase

Comment: @user9344362 Please read my comments and help me. I tried the following but it didnt help me. 
runner.project.testSuites["TestSuite 4"].testCases["TestCase 1"].testSteps["tc1_script2"].run(runner,context)
context.getTestRunner().project.testSuites["TestSuite 4"].testCases["TestCase 1"].testSteps["tc1_script2"].run(runner,context)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a `TestCaseRunner` at that point. You can make your own.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner

def testCase = runner.testSuite.project
    .testSuites["TestSuite 4"]
    .testCases["TestCase 1"]

def testRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner(testCase, new StringToObjectMap())
testRunner.runTestStepByName("tc1_script2")

assert testRunner.runContext.obj
```

Comment: Thanks sir..you nailed it..i found another way to run that but the only overhead is creating a disabled testcase/script in the testsuite and calling it by using the following code. is it the right process? or bad?                                         
              testSuite.getTestCaseByName("TestCase 1").run((com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap)context, true)
 mobj=(com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap)context.getProperty("obj")
 log.info(mobj.fun())